# How to change the colour of a cell if the value is less than 2 other cells

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

Sorry if this seems too simple to ask here, but i have literally started using google sheets a few hours ago.

I would like cell F5 to change colour if the value in it is less than the values in both G5 and H5. not less than either, it needs to be less than both.

Answer (score 1):

Try clicking Format > Conditional formatting > Custom formula is:

`=AND(F5<>"",F5<G5,F5<H5)`

Apply it to range F5 and select a coloured background

Comment: now how do i get it to copy the formula to all the cells underneath?

Comment: ie =AND(F6<>"",F6<G6,F6<H5)     f and g need to change rows, h stays the same

Comment: try this formula and apply it to range F:F   =AND($F1<>"",$F1<$G1,$F1<$H1)  It will continue to calculate down the whole column.